# Nokia Lumia 830 camera problem

Tags: camera

The camera keeps turning on and taking pictures. Soft reset doesn't make it stop. I'm wondering if the button has become damaged. It launches and takes pictures a lot of them. Changed every setting I can find. I just want to disable the camera all together until I can get to the AT&T store to resolve or replace it. Can it be disabled completely so I can at least use my phone until then? Thank you!

Comment: Seems like a hardware (button) problem... go to the camera settings and deactivate the long press on the shutter button (if you have it)

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same problem. The phone kept continuously opening the camera and taking photos, trying to do something was almost impossible. It started from nothing (didn't fall or take water), so my first thought was a virus (even though I haven't found no one reporting it) or camera software gone stupid.

Since a soft reset didn't work, **I did a hard reset, restore to factory WP8 (it had WP10) and it solved the problem.**